# What does this regex mean and why

Tags: regex, sed

```
sed "s/\(^[a-z,0-9]*\)\(.*\)\( [a-z,0-9]*$\)/\1\2 \1/g" desired_file_name
```

*I apreciate it even if you only explain part of it or at lest structure it with words as in `s\alphanumerical_at_start\something\alphanumerical_at_end\something_else\global`*

Could someone explain what that means, why and are all regEx so ... awful ?

I know that it replaces the first lowcase alphanumerical word with the last one. But could you explain bit by bit what's going on here ? what's with all the `/\` and `\(.*\)\` and everything else ?

I'm just lost.

**EDIT:** Here is what I do get: `(^[a-z0-9]*)` starting with a trough z and 0 trough 9; and `[a-z,0-9]*$` is the same but the last word (however `[0-9,a-z]` = just first 2 characters / first character, or the entire word ?). Also: what does the `*` or the `\(.*\)\` even mean ?

Comment: *"why and are all regEx so … awful"* cannot be a serious question of your's. Things aren't automatically awful just because they escape your level of understanding.

Comment: Lol @"your level of understanding", no ofc not (I am here to learn after all), they are awful because ... look at it. It is 100% repulsive. For example I think python code looks amazing (as in easy to read) while c++ is less attractive (not that bad though). This on the other hand *shrug*. But if you have no useful comment, please refrain from commenting in the first place, thank you :)

Comment: I don't find regexes repulsive. I find them elegant and beautiful.

Comment: @KendallFrey I wish I could share that view. I for one hope to not use them very often but would like to understand them nonetheless

Comment: @Kalec The comment was useful. Your current level of understanding is "what does that even mean?!". This is like belittling a foreign language you don't speak because it all sounds like gibberish to you. That's not a useful position to have, and that was my point.

Comment: @Tomalak I do understand they are extremely useful, I have no doubt about that. It's just that they are so incredibly difficult to read at times. I now know the first character after `s` is the separator so i can use `_` to avoid `/\` which for me helped immensely. Still your first comment was not constructive at all.

Comment: @Kalec You must admit that "why are regexes so awful" isn't very constructive either. ;) I didn't mean it personal, so no offence. Apart from that I *did* provide a constructive answer.

Comment: @Tomalak I suppose I took it a bit too personal. Also I suppose I shouldn't state my personal opinions in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a sed search and replacement, which as the form `s/search/replace/flags`, the only flag is `g` which means that the search/replace is global, so if the match occurs multiple times on a single line instead of only the first one.

First, here is the regex it searches for:

```
\(^[a-z,0-9]*\)\(.*\)\( [a-z,0-9]*$\)
```

Or in a more readable format:

```
\(             # start capture group 1
  ^              # match at the beginning of the line
  [a-z,0-9]*     # zero or more alphanumeric or comma characters (lowercase only)
\)             # end capture group 1
\(             # start capture group 2
  .*             # zero or more of any character (except for newlines)
\)             # end capture group 2
\(             # start capture group 3
  [ ]            # literal ' ' character (I added brackets for clarity)
  [a-z,0-9]*     # zero or more alphanumeric or comma characters (lowercase only)
  $              # match at the end of the line
\)             # end capture group 3
```

Here is the replacement:

```
\1\2 \1
```

This will replace the entire line (because of the `^` and `$` anchors in the regex) with the contents of capture group 1, followed by the contents of capture group 2, then a space, then the contents of capture group 1.

Comment: Can you explain why do we need to escape the parentheses? I know that we need to, but I don't know why, so I'm asking.

Comment: the [ ] for ' ' helped immensely. I just need to clarify somethign: [0-9,a-z] represents an entire word that match these criteria until a white space ?

Comment: [0-9,a-z] matches only a single character. Needs [0-9,a-z]* for any number of chars until whitespace

Comment: @Kalec: `[0-9,a-z]` matches any character that is alphanumeric, or comma. The `*` says that match the previous token, which is `[0-9,a-z]`, for any number of it, _greedily_.

Comment: then `\(.*\)\` - capture 2 means the entire line ? When I use this, it replaces the last word with the first, but in my head it should double the first word and then also add it as the last word, without over-writing anything. Where am I mistaken ?

Comment: @nhahtdh - The parentheses need to be escaped in sed because that is the regular expression syntax that it supports.  Here is the [documentation on the regular expression syntax used by sed](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Regular-Expressions).

Comment: @Kalec - The `.*` will match as much as it can, but since the entire expression must match it will stop matching at the last space character, so that the final group can match.

Comment: So then, it does not pass over the line multiple times, just once ? also @F.J it it stops at the last space character BECAUSE there is another group ? What if it had failed to "pass the condition" would it still have went all the way to the end or just the final white space ?

Comment: @Kalec - Correct, the `g` option here doesn't have any effect.  This can be explained by the greediness of the regex, or because of the anchors to the beginning and end of the line (`^` and `$` respectively).

Comment: @Kalec - The `.*` will initially match until the end of the line, at which point the regex engine will look at the next element in the regex and try to match a space, but it will fail because there are no more characters left.  At this point backtracking occurs, where the `.*` will "give up" characters that it had previously matched until the entire regex can match successfully.  If the regex cannot match, then no replacement is performed.  This is why you wouldn't see any replacement here if the last word on a line had a capitalized character.

Comment: @F.J Thank you, I now understand how (this) regex works in it's entirety.

Answer (score 1):

- (^[a-z,0-9]) - alphanumerical or comma at start of a line (group 1)
- (.) - arbitrary character (group 2)
- ( [a-z,0-9]*$) - a space followed by zero or more alphanumericals or commas [guess the comma is just an error], to the end of a line
- \1\2 \1 - replace by (group 1)(group 2) space (group 1)
- g - everywhere in the input

Comment: \1\2 \1 I still don't get it. Replaces what with what. and ` \(.*\)\ ` is for me by far the most confuzing

Comment: `\1` - is a backward to catch(group) in regex: /(w+)0\1/ is a every word, that has this pattern `part0part`

Comment: @Alexander: There were several backslashes and asterisks that didn't appear in the question because the OP didn't use StackOverflow's excellent code formatting capabilities.  Check it again, and please use code formatting yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions are a method of describing regular grammars. They accomplish this in a very concise and very efficient way. This makes them look complicated.

They are also structured and decodeable.

First, there is a `sed` call.

```
sed "{operation}/{expression}/{replacement}/{modifiers}" {argument}
```

Note

- that `sed` separates the parts with forward slashes. This means you cannot have an unescaped forward slash in `{expression}` or `{replacement}`.
- that unlike most other regex dialets, `sed` uses parentheses to match actual parentheses and *escaped* parentheses to define capturing groups.

The `{operation}` happens to be `s` - substitute.

The `{expression}` is `\(^[a-z,0-9]\)\(.*\)\( [a-z,0-9]*$\)`, which breaks down as

```
\(             # start capture group 1
  ^            #   match the start of the string
  [a-z,0-9]    #   match characters a-z and 0-9 and a comma (!)
\)             # end capture group 1
\(             # start capture group 2
  .*           #   match any character (.), zero or more times (*)
\)             # end capture group 2
\(             # start capture group 3
               #   match a space
  [a-z,0-9]*   #   match characters a-z and 0-9 and a comma (!)
  $            #   match the end of the string
\)             # end capture group 3
```

Just think for a second, how much code (and time) it would take you to write a function that does the same, and how little space a regex needs. That's why it's harder to read - it's extremely compressed.

The `{replacement}` is `\1\2 \1`. `\n` is called a back-reference, where `n` is the number ofthe capturing group. So this inserts the contents of groups 1 and 2, a space and the contents of group 1 again.

The `{modifiers}` part is a `g` flag, that makes the regex apply as often as possible. In this special case it doesn't make much sense since the regex above can only ever match once anyway.

Comment: If `operation` was something other than substitution, the syntax would be different and there would be no `expression` and `replacement`. So I'd start explaining with `s/{expression}/{replacement}/{modifiers}`. Anyway, good answer.

Comment: @Lev: That's right, I just wanted to pull apart the bits as much as possible.

Comment: A little bit of regression, but to demonstrate the point that Tomalak made about code and time to write a function that regex can do, this problem (http://uva.onlinejudge.org/external/100/10058.html) can be solved within 20 LOCs of (clean) Java code with the help of regex, but takes lots more time and code in pure C.

Answer (score 1):

```
s/\(^[a-z,0-9]*\)\(.*\)\( [a-z,0-9]*$\)/\1\2 \1/g

s -> substitute
/ -> begin of regex
\( -> begin of a first field( accessed as \1 later)
^  -> from the begining of line in data
[a-z,0-9] -> list of characters which will be compared, lowercase a through z, comma, and 0 through 9
* -> zero or more times
\) -> end of \1 field
\( -> begin of \2
.* -> . means any character. .* means any character zero or more times
\) -> end of \2
\( [a-z,0-9]*$ -> begin of \3, followed by a space, follwed by zero or more a-z, comma, 0-9
\) -> end of \3 field
/ -> end of regex to replace

/ -> begin of regex to replace with
\1\2 \1 -> first field followed by second field followed by a space and again the first field
/ -> end of regex to replace with

g -> globally
```